# Viterbi algorithm for finding most probable path with varying transition probabilities

Tags: hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

I'm struggling to apply the Viterbi algorithm to a simple case of inferring hidden states where the transmission probabilities change. I've draw a picture below of the trellis with transition probabilities on arrows and emission probabilities in the blue boxes. It should be obvious that the most probable path given the observed (green) sequence `abbb` is `XXYY` (prob 0.0405, with the bold arrows).

My (probably poor) understanding of the Viterbi algorithm (e.g. from http://cecas.clemson.edu/~ahoover/ece854/refs/Gonze-ViterbiAlgorithm.pdf ) is shown below the trellis, with a grey background. Calculating the probabilities from left to right, and taking the maximum likelihood value at each step, results in the wrong path taken in this case (XXXY: prob=0.018). What's my misunderstanding here? And how can I efficiently find the most probable path in this case?

[image: Hidden states model with varying transition probabilities and a sub-optimal Viterbi path]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is my misunderstanding of the Viterbi algorithm. To calculate e.g. the lattice probabilities for the second state being X, I need to take the *maximum* over both paths from the first state: i.e. prob(X in second state) = max(state Y -> X; state X -> X) =  max(0.45, 0.0) = 0.45. In other words, the correct diagram is as follows:

[image: Corrected Viterbi path diagram]